# Peano axioms: S(1)=1?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, peano-axioms

I was reading through the Peano axioms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), and a question came up:

Can we define $S(0)=1$, and $S(1)=1$?

It seems to me (at least as it is stated) that it would satisfy all of the axioms listed.
And I couldn't find any restrictions on the successor function, which would disallow this.

So would this be a valid Peano arithmetic or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: If $S(1)=1=S(0)$, then $0=1$ by Axiom 7 in the link.

Comment: This is still not a problem on its own, the contradiction arises with Axiom 8 which says that $0$ is not a successor, but $0=1$ implies $S(0)=1=0$.

Comment: @logarithm: Yes, if we're not considering $=$ to be built into the logic (but the Wikipedia article is equivocal about that).

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Successor_Mapping_of_Peano_Structure_has_no_Fixed_Point deals with this situation. In essence, it would be a "fixed-point" over $S$ and disallowed by the injectivity axiom -- as given in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your structure fails to satisfy the axiom that the Wikipedia article gives number 7:

> 7. For all natural numbers $m$ and $n$, $m = n$ if and only if $S(m) = S(n)$. That is, $S$ is an injection.

Comment: Ah! I see. Didn't see the "only if" part.

Thanks!

Comment: @Valdeminas: It's actually the "if" direction that sinks your structure.

Comment: $\{0\}$ with $S(0)=0$ satisfies Axiom 7. It is Axiom 8, the one that fails.